# Помогите пожалуйста советом

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, kaggle

я пока что начинающий в data science и хотел бы спросить у более опытных, не могли бы вы сказать какие темы надо знать в машинном обучении, чтобы выполнить самое просто задание на kaggle такое как Титаник например? Просто я дошел до логистической регрессии, и не знаю надо еще, что то изучить, чтобы начать решать простые задачи с kaggle или надо еще что то выучить. Так сказать, назовите пожалуйста необходимую базу:)

Answer (score 1):

А зачем вам Титаник. Там есть и другие задания, попытайтесь решать их. Найдите те, которые вы можете решить уже известными вам методами.

А вообще странная постановка задачи. Учить метод, что-бы решить учебную задачу. Обычно при учебе делают наоборот - учат тему, а под нее подбирают задачИ. И так переходя от одной темы к другой ПОСТЕПЕННО осваивают разные методы, алгоритмы и подходы.

И вообще, kaggle -  не учебник, по нему не учатся.  Это по сути - задачник. Его используют для закрепления знаний, полученных при обучение.

Ну и "не знаю что учить дальше" - тоже странное заявление. Вы что не по книгам учите, где какие- то темы (часто с примерами, между прочим) уже сформулированы и излагаются в обдуманным автором-специалистом порядке? И даже не по каким-нибудь видосикам?  А так, что решили по велению свыше или непонятному совету на форуме?

Comment: Cогласен, моя постановка задачи была не особо корректная, я просто хочу научиться решать задачи, кроме как из kaggle я не знаю где их брать, и в силу своей неопытности, хочу понять какую базу нужно иметь, чтобы решить самую простую задачу от туда, про Титаник я говорю, потому что его все ставят в пример как 1-ая задача на kaggle

Comment: Да не задачи надо учиться решать! Надо изучать предмет, а уж потом с помощью полученных знаний решать задачи! Вы же хотите стать специалистом в DataSсience, а не специалистом по решению задач с kaggle. А это вовсе не одно и тоже.

Comment: ладно я Вас, понял , тут  вопрос был совершенно в другом , Вы мне пишете как мне надо или не надо, пожалуйста не пишите сюда больше

Comment: Вопрос заключался в следующем, какую базу тем надо знать , чтобы уже пойти решать самые простые задачи, а не в Вашей бесполезной критики

Comment: Ну, если моя критика безполезна - значит в моих советах  и ссылках вы не нуждаетесь.  Вы даже не дали себе труд понять почему я это вам советую. Ладно, оставайтесь со своим огромным опытом на едине. Удачи  в самообучении.